# How to list all the routes of a routing table in Azure-classic portal?

Tags: powershell, azure

Ok, I am down and out and gone. I am trying to to list all the routes of a routing table that someone else has created in my organization inside Azure. Long story short- I need to disable the force tunneling that was enabled previously and for that i need to delete the default route that was created in the routing table.

I know i have to use remove-azureroute for it but i want to see the route first.

`Get-AzureRouteTable` only list the name of the routing table but not the routes. I know we can do this with Get-AzureRmRouteConfig in ARM but how to do this with classic portal?

Maybe the answer is really simple but it is driving me crazy right now.. please help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it.. damn stupid documentation, it was a -detailed switch!

Get-AzureRouteTable -name nameofyourroutingtable -detailed